# Entities doing too much?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, architecture, dependencies

I having an old puzzle, so I thought I'll share it with you, may be will get right direction.
Thing is, that some of our entities in database are quite big (read have many properties), and rarely business logic uses all of entity properties, so every time I need to think what properties must be loaded for business logic to work correctly. Very hypothetical sample:

```
public class Product 
{
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}

    public string RetailPrice {get;set;}
    public string SupplierId {get;set;}

    public Supplier Supplier { get;set;}

    // many other properties
}

public class ProductDiscountService
{
    public decimal Get(Product product)
    {
        // use only RetailPrice and Supplier code
        return discount;
    }
}

public class ProductDescriptionService 
{
    public string GetSearchResultHtml(Product product) 
    {
        // use only Title and Description
        return html;
    }
}
```

It looks like I could extract interfaces IDiscountProduct and ISearchResultProduct, mark product as implementing those interfaces, then create smaller DTOs implementing each of those interfaces, but that looks at the moment as overkill (at least I haven't seen anyone grouping properties using interfaces).

To split entity in database to smaller entities also doesn't look reasonable, as all those properties belong to product and I'm afraid I'll be forced to use many joins to select something and if I'll decide that some property belongs to another entity, that move will be quite hard to implement.

To have every property used in particular method's business logic as method parameter also looks like bad solution.

Comment: How many properties are we talking about?

Comment: usually more than 10, less than 20.

Comment: I would say: if your method knows in advance which properties to use and this stays fixed, than using parameters might be a good solution. Easy to test and easy to reuse. However, if the implementation is undefined in the method signature (current implementation uses 2 properties but tomorrow these might become 3), you want to consume the whole Product thing with all properties available. This speaks in a consistent way: This method requires these parameters and this method requires a product.

Comment: I hope that blog post about lazy loading properties could help: http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/07/01/lazy-loading-properties-in-linq-to-sql.aspx

Comment: Why are your service classes getting product as argument? wouldn't be better to pass only id to service method and load only some specific data from DB?

Comment: @MajoB - well, that is for several reasons. First, if you have 10 services, that run on same product and each service would load data by itself, you would kick database really hard. Also it is easier to test business logic, when it is not mixed with data access logic.

Comment: @defaultlocale - didn't knew, that I can make properties as lazy loading, and it would be great solution, but it hits database quite hard, if you have to process 1000 items, because what you've could load in single query, it becomes 1000 queries using lazy loading...

Answer (score 1):

Unless the properties are big (read long strings and/or binaries) I'd just load them all.

The points below are for simple properties (e.g. Title)

1. No extra code  (get this product with title only, or get with price only, blah-blah)
2. A product instance is always complete, so you can pass it around without checking if the property is null.
3. If you'll have to lazy-load some other properties, it'll cost you more than loading them eagerly.  If you have like 20 properties - this isn't even a big object (again, if your (hypothetical) Description property is not kilobytes in size).

Now, if you have related objects (ProductSupplier) - this should be lazy-loaded, imo, unless you know this property will be used.

Comment: Well, in real project description is html, so several kilobytes is usual case. Another thing is, that because of nature of our business model, we usually process large amounts of products (thousands), so lazy loading is not acceptable because of large query count. So if you have thousands of products and kilobytes in properties, it becomes quite important what you load from database :) I was thinking about placing some quick read storage like reddis in between, as long as there are much more reads than writes.

Comment: Depends on a type of processing. When we had to work with large set of data in the past - we just loaded it into memory, and worked from there, but that set was read-only.. and we ended up dropping that solution and going back to database.   Anyways, in your case I think I'd measure how often do you actually need the properties, and what is the actual impact of loading them eagerly.  I still don't think that several Kb per record is that much - even if you have a few (5-10?) thousands of records, that's just a few MB to be read. Having a proper indexes would be a lot more important.

Comment: Reddis or memcached could be worth a look too.  Depends on your needs, but something like RavenDB might help as well.

Comment: I've just checked our products table - it is 475mb on disk, so even if it is cached most of the times in memory, still quite an amount of data to move from one place to another ;)